# Java Strange Float Behavior

Tags: java, floating-point

Here is what my code looks like stripped down as much as possible:

```
    float delay = (float)5000;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int elapsed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            elapsed = (int) ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);
//          System.out.println("Elapsed: " + elapsed);
            float range = delay * 0.4f;
            float randomNum = (float)(Math.random() * range - (delay * 0.2f));
            if (elapsed > (delay + randomNum)) {
                System.out.println("Random Num: " + randomNum);
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
            } else {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
        }
```

As you can see I'm looping 20 times and printing out a random number after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds). This is what the output looks like:

[image]

As you can see, all of the outputs are VERY close to -1000. I'm trying to generate a random float from -1000 to 1000, but they all seem to be around -1000. So, I checked to make sure the actual random number generator is working, using this code:

```
    float delay = (float)5000;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int elapsed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            elapsed = (int) ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);
//          System.out.println("Elapsed: " + elapsed);
            float range = delay * 0.4f;
            float randomNum = (float)(Math.random() * range - (delay * 0.2f));                  
            System.out.println("Random Num: " + randomNum);
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
```

Basically I took elapsed out of the equation and just printed the random numbers without the if statement. This is the output I got:

[image]

In this example, I got very random output, exactly like you would expect. However, once you add elapsed back into the equation like in the first set of code, the output turns back to -999 with some random decimal places.

Even more interesting is that if you put a print statement right above the if statement and right after `randomNum` is assigned a value, you get these outputs:

[image]

Once again, the numbers are random. It seems like for some reason in the first example code with the elapsed part of the code put in, the `randomNum` variable changes right after the if statement is called. Why does this happen?

Comment: What is the type of `range`? Can you boil this down to a self-contained example?  You've omitted enough critical information that it will be hard for anyone to help, and the question may get closed.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it down as much as possible. All the code you see in this question is running inside a main method without ANY other outside code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, although you're generating random numbers in your desired range, you're systematically discarding all the ones over `-999`.

Consider code like this:

```
while (true) {
    // generate a random number in the range [-1000, 1000):
    final double randomNum = 2000 * Math.random() - 1000;

    // print it if it's in the range [-1000, -999):
    if (randomNum < -999) {
         System.out.println("Random Num: " + randomNum);
    }
}
```

The above code will print out a bunch of random numbers in the range [−1000, −999); do you see why?

Your code is more complicated, of course, but it's effectively doing the same thing.

To see why, let's take a look at your code:

```
    float delay = (float)5000;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int elapsed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            elapsed = (int) ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);
//          System.out.println("Elapsed: " + elapsed);
            float range = delay * 0.4f;
            float randomNum = (float)(Math.random() * range - (delay * 0.2f));
            if (elapsed > (delay + randomNum)) {
                System.out.println("Random Num: " + randomNum);
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
            } else {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Let's simplify/trim it a bit so it's easier to read — remove the commented-out line, clean up the whitespace, remove the casts to `int` and `float` (it's OK to use `long` and `double`), inline the various values, change the `for`-loop-that-contains-code-that-mutates-its-index-variable into a more-explicit `while`-loop, change the `System.nanoTime()`-but-then-dividing-the-result-by-a-million to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, rename some variables for clarity, etc.:

```
long prevTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
int i = 0;
while (i < 20) {
    final long elapsedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - prevTimeMillis;
    final double randomNum = 2000 * Math.random() - 1000;
    if (elapsedMillis > 5000 + randomNum) {
        System.out.println("Random Num: " + randomNum);
        prevTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Even with that simpler code in hand, we still need two key insights:

- `elapsedMillis > 5000 + randomNum` is just another way of writing `randomNum < elapsedMillis - 5000`.
- Initially, `elapsedMillis == 0`; and after each time we successfully print out a number, `elapsedMillis == 0` again. In between, there are some loop iterations where `elapsedMillis` increases by `1`, but in most loop iterations it doesn't change at all.

  - This is because this loop is very very quick, with a very large number of iterations per millisecond. (That's not necessarily obvious from first principles, but it's the only way to explain the output you're getting.)

So this code will loop quickly, generating one random number after another and discarding every single one, until `elapsedMillis == 4001`, at which point every random number will be discarded *except* random numbers less than `-999`. Since you're performing a huge number of loop iterations per millisecond, and generating a huge number of random numbers per millisecond, it's overwhelmingly likely that you manage to generate a random number less than `-999` while `elapsedMillis == 4001`. And then `elapsedMillis` gets reset back to zero. So random numbers greater than `-999` never have a chance to compete: `elapsedMillis` is never greater than `4001`, so such numbers are always discarded.

To fix this, you need to pre-select a single random number "How long should I delay?" *before* you start looping, and then loop until your `elapsedMillis` exceeds that one pre-selected random number.

In addition, assuming that your real goal here is to delay for some amount of time in the range [4sec,6sec), you should probably use `Thread.sleep()` rather than this polling/busy-waiting mechanism. That way, instead of just burning CPU, you can gracefully yield this processor for use by other threads and processes until you're ready to proceed. To do that, you can write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    final long millisToDelay = (long) (2000 * Math.random() - 1000);
    System.out.println("Millis To Delay: " + millisToDelay);
    Thread.sleep(millisToDelay);
}
```

Comment: That's very smart! Good job for catching that, and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually have the answer to your problem located on the second line of code you have provided to us. Notice how you cast to float: (float)?

Do the same thing on the line that contains:

> float number = delay + randomNum;

so that it looks like:

> float number = (float) delay + randomNum;

delay is not a float data type. I think that should do it.

Comment: delay is a float type. I have this  code "float delay = (float)delayMS;" and delayMS is an int.